# MySQL error checking showing false positive

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm working on a script that does a series of error checking regarding MySQL databases.

First it checks to see if the database exists using the root credentials:

```
until [[ ! -z "`mysql -h $dbHost -u $dbRoot -p$mysqlRootPwd -qfsBe "SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME='$dbName'" 2>&1`" ]];
```

Then, it uses the same check to make sure the specified user actually has permission to use the database

```
until [[ ! -z "`mysql -h $dbHost -u $dbUser -p$dbPass -qfsBe "SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME='$dbName'" 2>&1`" ]];
```

The second one passes with a false positive, but not when run on it's own. This leads me to believe that it's still checking with the root credentials for some reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not try `echo "$dbUser $dbPass"`?

Comment: To find out what's going on, remove the `>/dev/null 2>&1` and you could query `SELECT CURRENT_USER();` to verify your findings.

Comment: @Max - I've verified that $dbUser and $dbPass have the correct values.

Comment: So then you know that it is not running as root. Try running the code  @Jack posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by using the mysqlshow command instead.

```
dbTestUser=mysqlshow --host=$dbHost --user=$dbUser --password=$dbPass $dbName| grep -v Wildcard | grep -o $dbName

dbTestRoot=mysqlshow --host=$dbHost --user=$dbRoot --password=$mysqlRootPwd $dbName| grep -v Wildcard | grep -o $dbName
```

And then `if [ -z $dbTestUser ]` to verify the test was working properly.